# Getting the coordinates of a specific point out of a plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-value

I have the following piece of code that in the first part calculates and plots a function and it uses it in the second part to perform an NDSolve. After that I am plotting two functions. What I would like to know is how can I get the precise coordinates for the point that the two graphs meet.

This is the code

```
(*UV cuttoff*)
rmax = 10;
(*Number of colours and flavours*)
nc = 3;
nf = 2;
(*number of flavours used to calculate f\[Pi]*)
nfp = 1 ;
(*mir=260;*) (*IR mass (If using UV mass comment out)*)
muv = \
0.05;(*UV mass (IF using IR mass comment this and the line to \
calculate mir later)*)

(*Value of \[Alpha][1] compare to output at end to tune for \[Delta]*)
\
\[Alpha]1 = 0.7 ;

b0 = (11 nc - 2 nf)/(6 \[Pi]) ;

b1 =  1/(24 \[Pi]^2) (34 nc^2 - 10 nc nf  - 3 (nc^2 - 1) nf/nc) ;

eqalp1 = alp1'[mu1] + (b0 alp1[mu1]^2 + b1 alp1[mu1]^3) == 0;


sol1 = NDSolve [{ eqalp1, alp1[0] == \[Alpha]1}, 
   alp1, {mu1, 0, 10^24}];

alph1[mu1_] := First[Evaluate[alp1[mu1] /. sol1]]

alph1[mu1];
\[Alpha][mu_] := alph1[mu]
\[Gamma][mu1_] := 3 (nc^2 - 1)/(4 nc \[Pi]) \[Alpha][mu1]
(*The square of the mass*)
\[Delta][mu1_] := -2 \[Gamma][mu1]
(*The value at zero*)
\[Delta][0]
Plot[\[Delta][\[Rho]], {\[Rho], 0, 2 rmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Yellow}, 
 BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", 
   "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalDelta]m\), \(2\)]\)(\[Rho])"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 2 rmax}, {-1, 0}}]
```

The plot from the above

[image: The mass squared]

The second part of the code is

```
ode := D[r^3 L'[r], r] - \[Delta][Log[Sqrt[r^2 + L[r]^2] ]] r L[r] == 0
solm[v_] := NDSolve[{ode, L[v ] == v,
    L'[v] == 0}, L, {r, v, rmax}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 13, AccuracyGoal -> 13] // 
  First
LinfBm[ v_?NumericQ ] := (L[rmax] /. solm[v]) - muv
(*Find mir from muv (comment out if using mir*)
mir = 
 m /. FindRoot[LinfBm[m], {m, 1}]
lf[\[Rho]_] := Evaluate[L[\[Rho]] /. solm[ mir]]
Show[Plot[lf[r], {r, mir, 10 mir}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "L(\[Rho])"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10 mir}, {0, 2 mir}}], 
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 2 mir}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]]
```

[image: The brane embedding]

I would like a way as I mentioned in the beginning to find the coordinates of the point where the two functions meet in this final plot.

Comment: `{r, lf[r]} /. FindRoot[lf[r] == r, {r, 0.7}]` evaluates to `{0.659885, 0.659885}`

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems simple and something I should have thought, but I've been struggling for hours. Cheers!!!